# How to make gcc skip preprocessing?

Tags: c, clang

I want to do some testing and want the input file to be passed to the c compiler directly, not being preproecssed. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this in a `C` compliant compiler.

Comment: You can look to see whether there's a way to substitute a do-nothing command for the preprocessor.  Nominally, it is similar to `cat`, except you need it to ignore most of the options it is passed.  It won't be easy.  It is also surprising.  If the code is going to compile despite not being run through the preprocessor, it must mean the preprocessor will do nothing, so it won't matter whether or not the preprocessor is actually used.

Comment: The `-fpreprocessed` option tells the *gcc* compiler the input file has already been preprocessed. That suppresses most of the preprocessing task.

Comment: @ring0 it complains "error: unknown argument: '-fpreprocessed'"

Comment: Hmmm old version? Works on mine... How do you use it? Try `gcc -Wall -fpreprocessed myprettyprog.c -o myprettyprog`

Comment: @ring0 gcc in my machine is a symbolic link to clang

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the source file that you do not want to be preprocessed is a C source file `foo.c` then rename it to `foo.i`. If it is a C++ source file then
rename it to `foo.ii`. This will cause the compiler to skip preprocessing. Just compile as usual, e.g.

```
gcc -c -o foo.o foo.i
```

However, if you try to compile a source file that contains preprocessing directives ('#'-lines) without preprocessing it then
the compilation will simply fail, like:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    puts("Hello world");
    return 0;
}

$ cp foo.c foo.i
$ gcc -c -o foo.o foo.i
foo.i:1:1: error: stray ‘#’ in program
 #include <stdio.h>
 ^
foo.i:1:10: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘<’ token
 #include <stdio.h>
      ^
```

Possibly what you want to do is compile a source file that you have already preprocessed without
preprocessing it again. In that case, first preprocess `foo.c`, writing the output to `foo.i`,
then compile `foo.i`:

```
$ cpp foo.c > foo.i
$ gcc -c -o foo.o foo.i
$ gcc -o foo foo.o
$ ./foo
Hello world
```

Presumably you would do something with, or to, `foo.i` between creating it and compiling it;
otherwise you might as well just compile `foo.c`.

> gcc in my machine is a symbolic link to clang

OS X? No matter: you can substitute `clang` for `gcc` throughout the above.

[See also](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html)

Comment: Thank you! Great that this question wasn't deleted despite being downvoted, needed to search for this with many wordings. I need to intercept for one of my projects between preprocessing and compiling and I didn't want to repeat a stage, because I need it to be fast.